# Alias not exported from .zprofile to folder location that exists

Tags: command-line, mac, terminal, zsh, alias

In my .zprofile, I have a bunch of aliases that follow the same pattern:

```
export remotedir="$HOME/remote"
export localdir="$HOME/local"
```

etc.

They all work, except for one, which returns

`cd: no such file or directory: XXXXX`

If I `cd` directly into this directory, there is no problem. For security, I cannot write out the full directory here, but lets call it `/foo/bar` aliased with `$foodir`. To be clear, here is the terminal output:

```
~ % export foodir="/foo/bar"
~ % cd $foodir
cd: no such file or directory: /foo/bar
~ % cd /foo/bar

bar %
```

It does not matter if I alias `foodir` directly in the terminal, or if I copy this into my .profile.

Some details about the folder that might help:

- It's a Dropbox folder
- The path has spaces (***this was my first instinct, but see below)
- The alias used to work and a few months ago it stopped working
- Everything is escaped, e.g. Dropbox (Business) becomes `"Dropbox\ \(Business\)"`

Comment: The problem is probably that in the name of your directory are some special characters. As you cannot write it here, I can only speculate. Try something like `foodir='/foo/bar'` (single quotes!)

Comment: When you say "everything is escaped", do you mean there are backslashes stored in the variable's value (i.e. if you run `echo "$foodir", does it print backslashes)? If so, that's going to be a problem; backslashes in variables are treated as just part of the data in the variable, not as syntactic escapes.

Comment: @GordonDavisson This might be the problem! I am using `export foodir="$HOME/Dropbox\ \(Business\)"`, and if I try `echo` as you suggest, indeed the backslashes are printed. How do I fix this?

Comment: @user345435 Remove the backslashes. Note that if you try to use this variable in bash (or most other non-zsh shells) you'll need to put double-quotes around it when you use it.

Comment: Removing the backslashes worked. Oddly, using single quotes (also without backslashes) does _not_ work. So, the solution is to use no backslashes + double quotes: `export foodir="$HOME/Dropbox (Business)"`

Comment: @GordonDavisson Feel free to add this answer and I will accept it.